# Is it possible to get Date object in Android in dd-mm-yyyy format?

Tags: java, android

In Android all Date objects are given in this type of date format `"Mon Dec 03 00:13:21 GMT+05:30 2018"` when you convert it with `SimpleDateFormat`.

Is there any possibility of getting a Date object in the `"dd-mm-yyyy"` format in Android?

Comment: No, a `Date` cannot have a format. What you see is the return value from its `toString` method. As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the pattern on a [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) and format the date:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").format(new Date());
```

Comment: Incorrect answer. You need to watch the case of your format pattern letters.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `Strings` into `Dates` as the following:

```
String pattern = "dd-mm-yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());//firstly get formatted str
Date newDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(strDate);//then get date object with wanted format
```

Comment: sir when i conver back string into date that date object get "Mon Dec 03 00:13:21 GMT+05:30 2018"

Comment: Incorrect answer. You need to watch the case of your format pattern letters.